# What is the URL Scheme to open the IFTTT app to a specific channel?

Tags: ios

We have a button within our app to open the IFTTT app, but we'd love to be able to open the IFTTT app to our specific channel.  Is this possible?

Something like the following:

```
ifttt://channels/*our_channel*
```

or

```
ifttt://search?channel=*our_channel*
```

Comment: You should contact the developers of whatever app you are referring to.

Comment: This is not a question about programming, it's a customer service question for the app you are using. As rmaddy says, contact them.